# What does "pass it on" mean?

Tags: meaning, sentence, lyrics

I love the song *Pass It On* by *The Coral*, but I can't understand the meaning of this sentence:

> Just find the feeling, pass it on.

What does *pass it on* mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know the song, but *pass it on* normally means to share something with another or others, whether keeping it for oneself also or not, especially something received from a third party. Thus, for example, if someone smiles at you or greets you, you could be said to be passing it on if you smile at or greet someone else. If someone gives you a platter of chicken, you can take one piece for your plate and pass the platter on to the next person.

Answer (score 2):

I think in spanish you would say *pásala*. It means to give something you have received (usually something you have appreciated) to someone else. It's also used as a phrase in the game [Chinese Whispers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_whispers) to mean *relay what I said to the next person*.

> Have you had a kindness shown?
>   Pass it on;
>   ’Twas not given for thee alone,
>   Pass it on;
>  
>   Let it travel down the years,
>  
>   Let it wipe another's tears,
>   ’Til in Heaven the deed appears —
>  
>   Pass it on.
>   *~ Henry Burton, Pass It On*

Answer (score 0):

We are all put on this earth to help one another. The term "pass it on" means to share the blessings that you have been given to another person. It does not always mean giving money or property,a simple smile while opening the door for someone else while wishing them a good morning is the same